# JavaScript search names in array with Indexof

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, indexof

Hello guys I'm trying to get in a new array the all the people with the `Calderon` names in name in array.

Is it possible?

```
people = [
    {name: 'Felipe Calderon', year: 2012},
    {name: 'Rocio Calderon Martinez', year: 2012},
    {name: 'Laura Martinez Calderon', year: 2012},
    {name: 'Marcos Alberto Gonzales Calderon', year: 2012}, 
    {name: 'Brenda Calderon Ibañez', year: 2012},   
];
```

When I use `indexOf` on a string it works perfectly but not using array, it seems to work only id the name starts with `Calderon` but bot contains the word.

Answer (score 3):

To filter one array into another array, you need to use the filter() function:

```
let calderons = people.filter(person => person.name.indexOf('Calderon') >= 0);
```

Or, if you can't use lambda functions:

```
var calderons = people.filter(function(person) {
    return person.name.indexOf('Calderon') >= 0;
});
```

Comment: or just `includes` with `filter`.

Comment: If they can't use arrow functions, then they probably can't use `let` either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find the names which contains `Calderon` in it. Use [`string#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to search `Calderon` inside the `name` value.

```js
const people = [ {name: 'Felipe Calderon', year: 2012}, {name: 'Rocio Calderon Martinez', year: 2012}, {name: 'Laura Martinez Calderon', year: 2012}, {name: 'Marcos Alberto Gonzales Calderon', year: 2012}, {name: 'Brenda Calderon Ibañez', year: 2012}];
const result = people.filter(({name}) => name.includes('Calderon'));
console.log(result);
```